# TypeScript cannot infer array type in spread syntax function call

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, spread-syntax

I can spread an array as function/constructor arguments without any problem: (test.js)

```
class Person {
    name; 
    age;

    constructor(name, age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}

let a = ['Claire', 8];
let p = new Person(...a);

console.log(p);
```

However, the same thing doesn't work in TypeScript: (test.ts)

```
class Person {
    constructor(
        public name: string,
        public age: number
    ) {}
}

let a = ['Claire', 8];
let p = new Person(...a);  // Error: An argument for 'name' was not provided.

console.log(p);
```

Is this a bug in TypeScript? It cannot figure out how to use spread syntax here. Is there a workaround or I have to manually assign each individual argument?

Answer (score 4):

Option 1:

```
let a: [string, number] = ['Claire', 8];
```

---

Option 2:

```
let a = ['Claire', 8] as const;
```

This will tell TypeScript to treat `a` as a tuple containing `'Claire'` as its first item and `8` as its second which conforms to `[string, number]`. Without `as const` `a` was treated as a `(string | number)[]`.

Comment: is this different from declaring it as `const a = ['Claire', 8]`

Comment: @bryan60 the JavaScript result will be the same, TypeScript will treat it differently

Comment: @bryan60 `const a =` in that case will just tell that you won't reassign any value to this variable, it doesn't affect the type.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much! Now I understand the error is due to type incompatibility. The following code works (test.ts)

```
class Person {
    constructor(
        public name: string,
        public age: number
    ) {}
}

/* Spell out type or use 'as const' both work!
Or TypeScript treats ['Claire', 8] as of type (string | number)[]*/
let a: [string, number] = ['Claire', 8];
let b = ['Liam', 11] as const;

let p1 = new Person(...a);
let p2 = new Person(...b);

console.log(p1, p2);
```

Comment: Please mark the original answer as correct if it led you to a solution.