# Using Typescript variadic tuple type and Javascript Spread together

Tags: typescript

Need help understanding how the below piece of code works.

```
function concatFun<T extends any[], U extends any[]>(
  arg1: T[],
  arg2: U[]
): [...T, ...U] {
  const newArr = [...arg1, ...arg2]; // (T | U)[]
  return newArr; // error Type '(T | U)[]' is not assignable to type '[...T, ...U]'.
                 // Target requires 2 element(s) but source may have fewer.
}
```

I wanted the return type to be `[...T, ...U]`, but the return type is `(T | U)[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FIXED**
You need to infer literal type of provided arguments

```js
type Json =
  | null
  | string
  | number
  | boolean
  | Array<JSON>
  | {
    [prop: string]: Json
  }

function concatFun<
  Fst extends Json, T extends Fst[],
  Scd extends Json, U extends Scd[]>(
    arg1: [...T],
    arg2: [...U]
  ): [...T, ...U] {
  return [...arg1, ...arg2]

}

concatFun([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]) // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wEvAZN)

**Update**

```js
function concatFun<
  Fst extends Json, T extends Fst[],
  Scd extends Json, U extends Scd[]>(
    arg1: [...T],
    arg2: [...U]
  ) {
  const foo: [...T, ...U] = [...arg1, ...arg2]
  return foo
}
}
```

You can help TS to infer concatenated array. To be honest, I'm not sure how TS resolves it unfer the hood. But error message is pretty intuitive if you will et rid of explicit type  `[...T, ...U]` from `foo`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It way more neat. However, I still have hard time understanding, why is TS complain when i use assign spread and then return. 
[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBBECGUA8AVRBTADyjzABMBnRAJzzVIQBsBPRNMJgbQF0AaRAVXxESFarXphmrdtwB8ACgBQiVlQDmARgBcibD2Wq1AJh39FASh0cAdLb2Jb1-l0QBvAwHoPYqCCpIbWzR1DT5HYOMuAxQwcihEMDwAdwBBKipEAF5EQOsI0Icg9SMuAG4DGl9-BOS0qnKAX0VFGLjEKAALGDA1SmyY9Ch5DgAiYDg4Eb4RgCNgkZc0SlaoPlHgGAAvTanEWZBthdZlhDjzRSA)

Comment: @nitte93 made small update

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you meant:

```
function concat<T extends readonly any[], U extends readonly any[]>(
  arg1: T,
  arg2: U,
): [...T, ...U] {
  return [...arg1, ...arg2]
}
```

`T[]` means "array of `T`s", but not "`T` which is an array".

See this [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBBECGUA8AVRBTADyjzABMBnRAJzzVIQBsBPRNMJgbQF0AaRAVXxESFarXphmrdtwB8ACgBQiVlQDmARgBcibD2Wq1AJh39FASh0cAdLb2Jb1-l0QBvAzSggqSG7bTqGnyOAcZcigC+ioooYORQiFAAFjBgapQAvMioGPIcAETAcHD5fPkARgH5LmiUsfF8BcAwAF4tpYgVIG3VrHUI8eaKQA).

Comment: That definitely was a mistake and thanks for pointing it out. However, why is there a complain when I assign spread to a const and then return. 
[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBBECGUA8AVRBTADyjzABMBnRAJzzVIQBsBPRNMJgbQF0AaRAVXxESFarXphmrdtwB8ACgBQiVlQDmARgBcibD2Wq1AJh39FASh0cAdLb2Jb1-l0QBvAwHoPYqCCpIbWzR1DT5HYOMuAxQwcihEMDwAdwBBKipEAF5EQOsI0Icg9SMuAG4DGl9-BOS0qnKAX0VFGLjEKAALGDA1SmyY9Ch5DgAiYDg4Eb4RgCNgkZc0SlaoPlHgGAAvTanEWZBthdZlhDjzRSA)

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure. Perhaps it has to do with the ability to mutate the array afterwards? If you do `const newArr = [...arg1, ...arg2] as const`, `newArr` does get inferred as `readonly [...T, ...U]`. Perhaps [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61235755/typescript-cannot-infer-array-type-in-spread-syntax-function-call) is related?